# How can I measure the time taken by a web service to return an XML feed

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I want to compare various web services in terms of the fastness in serving XML feeds. I searched but did not find a tool for this. Please guide how can I measure the exact load time of the XML feed returned by a web service.

Comment: What language are you working with? .NET, Java, PHP?

Comment: I m working with android

Comment: Java then, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 0):

Just before you send request and after you receive response call System.currentTimeMillis() and subtract them